# Adding multiple text properties in D3.js tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I try to adapt a piece of code for a d3.js tree. Things work except that I can't find a way to add multiple text lines (that I want to style separately). It works with "fonction" but not with "fonction" **and** "nom".

```
{    
  "fonction": "blah1",
  "nom": "wah1",
  "type": "green", 
  "level": "green"
},   
{    
  "fonction": "blah2",
  "nom": "wah2",
  "type": "yellow", 
  "level": "yellow"
}
```

Here is part of the code used to append text:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + 
           "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
          .on("click", click);
           nodeEnter.append("circle")  
          .attr("r", function(d) { return d.value; })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.type; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d.level; });

          nodeEnter.append("text")
         .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; 
         })
         .attr("dy", ".35em")
         .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 
         "end" : "start"; })
         .text(function(d) { return d.fonction; })
         .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

If I copy the last block for returning d.nom, it works but only with the last one (for example d.nom instead of d.fonction, on the opposite if I reverse order.

I'm still trying to find a way to return both. It's the only missing part for having the tree that I try to set up but I'm a bit lost with it.

Thanks for any directions that could help...
Regards.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What happens if you do `.text(function(d) { return d.fonction + " " + d.nom;})`?

Comment: Oh, it works this way. I tried {return d.fonction + d.nom;} without success. But with the white space as a separator, it does. Many thanks for your help. By the way I can't help but agree: my question wasn't ideally composed, indeed.

Comment: What you just said (*"I tried {return d.fonction + d.nom;} without success"*) doesn't seem to make sense: it works the same way without that white space, have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/our4u22q/1/). You probably have another problem somewhere else.

Comment: True, again. Can't explain why. I have another problem, with the styles, but I'd rather ask this in another question.